# How do I get the charset on html 4 with node.js?

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, html4

Trying to get this charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

When I print the response headers:

```
console.log(response.headers);
```

I don´t get the charset, it should be inside the Content-type:

```
{ 
    server: 'Apache',
    'content-type': 'text/html',
    expires: 'Mon, 19 Jan 2015 11:53:58 GMT',
    'content-language': 'en', etag: '"95c66e83dfd2080ec86ec4e20964788d"',
    'x-pal-host': 'pal115.telhc.bbc.co.uk:80',
    'content-length': '120599',
    date: 'Mon, 19 Jan 2015 11:53:44 GMT', connection: 'keep-alive',
    ...
}
```

How can I get the charset on html 4 web sites in node.js?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<meta>` tags are not headers and so their value will not show up in the HTTP response's `headers` property. You'll need to parse the response body. This does raise an issue: how do you know how to parse something without knowing its encoding?

This is how web browsers roughly handle files that don't properly define their content type in the `Content-Type` header, last time I checked:

1. Start parsing the document body using a (user-defined) default, like `UTF-8`.
2. Guess what character set is used: For example, if there are a lot of bytes that are non-printable characters in `UTF-8` but they happen to be commonly used in `Shift JIS`, then you're probably dealing with that.
3. If the parser happens to detect one of the following:

   - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type">`
   - `<meta charset="">`
     Then partially parsed document is thrown out and parsing re-starts from the top of the file.

You can see why it's a good idea to always include the `Content-Type` header with a character set. For your application, you could leave out step 2, if you're not too worried about some documents being garbled.

As a nice example, StackOverflow itself sets a `Content-Type` header and so it has no (need for) `<meta charset>` or `<meta http-equiv="content-type">` tags.

Comment: The JSON object added on my question is actually what I´m getting from the response. When I print response.headers from an html5 site I get the charset correctly. Anyway I solve my problem creating a function using the cheerio npm package.

Comment: HTTP headers have nothing to do with the version of HTML used on the page. They're completely separate. The [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) is in HTML 4 and they set a proper HTTP header: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` (and a meta tag as a fallback).